# Different object with same identifier value

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm getting an error with "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" when I enter more than 1 person within the request call. The database will show that the first person is correctly inserted into the right tables but any subsequent person will not. The request is successful if only 1 person is in the request body but will return a database error if there is more than 1.

Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPENDENT")
data class Dependent (
        @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="applicationId")
        @MapsId
        val application: Application,

        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
        var person: Person?,

        var insuranceDeclined: Boolean,

        var medicalCondition: Boolean,

        var eligible: Boolean?,

        var referralUncompleted: Boolean
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dependentId")
    var id: Long? = null

    @Transient
    val name: String = person?.name ?: ""
}
```

Request Body:

```
data class DependentRequest (
        val persons: List<Person>,

        var insuranceDeclined: Boolean,

        var medicalCondition: Boolean,

        var eligible: Boolean?,

        var referralUncompleted: Boolean
) {

    fun dependent(application: Application): List<Dependent> {
        return persons.map { Dependent(application, it, insuranceDeclined, medicalCondition, eligible, referralUncompleted) }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
    fun createDependents(
            @RequestBody request: DependentRequest,
            @PathVariable("appId") appId: Long
    ): ResponseEntity<ResourceCreatedResponse> {
        logger.debug("Requested: POST /apps/$appId/dependents with body $request")

        val application = getApplication(appId)

        val dependentsList = request.dependent(application)
        for (item in dependentsList) {
            dependentRepo.save(item)
        }

        val location = getDependentLocation(application.id!!)
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(ResourceCreatedResponse(appId))
    }
```

Request Object:

```
{
    "persons": [{
                        "firstName": "Derek",
                        "lastName": "5",
                        "gender": "MALE"
                        },
                         {"firstName": "Joey",
                        "lastName": "5",
                        "gender": "MALE"
                        }],
    "insuranceDeclined": true,
    "medicalCondition": true,
    "eligible": true,
    "referralUncompleted": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share your request object?

Comment: @YoManTaMero added